# Force Maven to resolve version ranges with releases at build time

Tags: java, maven, build, release

We use version ranges that include SNAPSHOTS during development. When releasing, I want to force Maven to only resolve these ranges with non-SNAPSHOT versions. Is there any way to do this?

Ideally I'd like the release pom itself to resolve to specific versions (like versions:resolve-ranges) and then restore the ranges in the next development version, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist.

My next best idea is to find a way to convince Maven to ignore SNAPSHOTS completely during dependency resolution (via a build flag or plugin config). My first attempt - disabling remote snapshot repos via a release profile - does not solve the issue, because it still finds any SNAPSHOTS in my local .m2/repository even if the remote snapshot repo is disabled.

I should note that I'm not terribly concerned with reproducible release builds via POM, because our release artifacts are assembly JARs that pull in all unwrapped dependencies - so making ranges resolve to current releases during the build itself is good enough for me.

*I know: the canonical response is "versions ranges are bad". Suffice it to say that we have enough interdependent modules that get frequent enough updates and deployments that if we didn't use ranges, we would spend half our days updating dependency versions and releasing.*

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Furthermore are you building via `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: Maven 3.2.5. The normal build is "clean install", but custom phases / plugins don't scare me, we do plenty of custom build lifecycles. I just don't want to have to write an entirely new plugin for this.